# Read SiteMapNodeCollection of another sitecollection in a webapplication

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-online

I am having a three site collection along with subsite in a same Web Application as below

SiteCollection1
SubSite1.1
SubSIte1.2

SiteCollection2
SubSite2.1
SubSIte2.2

We have the requirment to create a custom navigation provider and point all sitecollection in a single menu control and each will have similer global menu as below. We don't want to go for HardCoded/SiteMap file as in our requirement whenever any new subsite added in sitecollection should reflect at same time.

`SiteCollection1`  `SiteCollection2`   //on mouse hower subsite will display

I am using below code to generate the same but my function `GetSiteMap` not able to read sitecollection2 `PortalSiteMapProvider` value from sitecollection1. while I change the line
 `childNodeB.ChildNodes = testchildNodeSiteB;` with  `childNodeB.ChildNodes = nodeColl;` it work fine and populate the value for current site.

enter code here

```
    public override SiteMapNodeCollection GetChildNodes(System.Web.SiteMapNode  node)
    {
        string url1 = "http://dev:111";   //this is current site collection
        string url2 = "http://dev:111/sites/Sitecollection2";
        PortalSiteMapNode pNode = node as PortalSiteMapNode;
        if (pNode != null)
        {
            if (pNode.Type == NodeTypes.Area)
            {
                SiteMapNodeCollection nodeColl = base.GetChildNodes(pNode);
                                   SiteMapNodeCollection test = new SiteMapNodeCollection();


                SiteMapNode childNode2 = new SiteMapNode(this, url2, url2, "SiteCollection2");

                nodeColl.Add(childNode2);

                SiteMapNodeCollection testchildNodeSite2 = GetSiteMap(url2);
                ***childNode2.ChildNodes = testchildNodeSite2;***


                return nodeColl;
            }
            else
                return base.GetChildNodes(pNode);
        }
        else
            return new SiteMapNodeCollection();
    }
    public SiteMapNodeCollection GetSiteMap(string url)
    {
        //using (SPWeb oWeb = SPContext.Current.Site.OpenWeb(guidWebsite))


        using (SPWeb spweb = SPContext.Current.Site.AllWebs[url])//new SPSite(url))
        {
            SPSite site = spweb.Site;

            SiteMapNodeCollection headingNodes = new SiteMapNodeCollection();
            headingNodes = null;

            PortalSiteMapProvider portalProvider = PortalSiteMapProvider.CurrentNavSiteMapProviderNoEncode;
            // Look up the node for the given Web site URL.
            PortalWebSiteMapNode webNode = portalProvider.FindSiteMapNode(url) as PortalWebSiteMapNode;

            if (webNode != null)
            {                        
                headingNodes = portalProvider.GetChildNodes(webNode, NodeTypes.Heading, NodeTypes.None);

            }
            return headingNodes;
        }


    }
```

Please suggest your views, how to read `SiteMapNodeCollection` of SiteCollection2 from SiteCollection1.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar requirement long before.

You may find this helpful :
  [How to get a reference of PortalSiteMapProvider object attached to a site that is not in current context](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/21411/how-to-get-a-reference-of-portalsitemapprovider-object-attached-to-a-site-that-i)